# Kundera with Datastax DS Driver Connection Port

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, kundera

I'm using Kundera with Datastax DS Driver for Cassandra connection.
On persistence.xml, I defined the port as 9042.

However, I noticed that that Kundera failed to connect to Cassandra:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.503 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.abc.DataServiceImplTest
writeReadTest(com.abc.DataServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.38 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.impetus.kundera.configure.schema.SchemaGenerationException: Error while opening socket, Caused by: .
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraSchemaManager.initiateClient(CassandraSchemaManager.java:718)
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.schema.api.AbstractSchemaManager.exportSchema(AbstractSchemaManager.java:112)
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraSchemaManager.exportSchema(CassandraSchemaManager.java:166)
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.SchemaConfiguration.configure(SchemaConfiguration.java:191)
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientMetadataBuilder.buildClientFactoryMetadata(ClientMetadataBuilder.java:48)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.configureClientFactories(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:408)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.configure(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

And once I enabled the Thrift port (9160) at /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml, things start working.

Here's the persistence.xml:

```
  <persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu">
<provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
<class>com.abc.Person</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

<properties>
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
        <property name="kundera.port" value="9042" />
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="testkeyspace" />
  <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update" />
  <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
       <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"
            value="com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory" />
  <property name="kundera.annotations.scan.package" value="com.abc.impl"/>
</properties>
```

Wonder if I need to enable 9160 even with using DS-Driver?

Thanks!

Comment: Kundera takes care of CRUD operations using datastax driver when using datastax module. But few features like auto schema generation are supported using Thrift port only.

Comment: Thanks.  So that means even I'm using DSDriver, The RPC server for Thrift still needs to remain open, is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct...

Comment: If you need not to auto manage schema via Kundera then 9160 should not be required. Disable kundera.ddl.auto.prepare and its all good. Schema creation is still via thrift way. Guess, it should be added at Kundera wiki till support gets enabled via DS driver.

Answer (score 1):

`kundera.ddl.auto.prepare` works via thrift way which works on port 9160 but you are using `com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory` provided by datastax & works on port 9042 as you have also mentioned in your `persistence.xml`. So ,

**removing this line**

`<property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update" />`

from your `persistence.xml` will solve this issue.